# Why is my Builder.load_file() a Nonetype?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to create an App using Python3.7 and KivyMD.
In Python, when I am trying to call a widget in my Kivy File by its ID, I have an AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute  "ids", and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
My both files are in the same folders, and my kivy file is name "bibot.kv"

Here is a part of Python code

```
class BiBOTApp(MDApp):
    page_chat = ""
    page_calendrier = ""
    
    def build(self):
        KV = Builder.load_file("bibot.kv") 
        print(type(KV))
        layout = BoxLayout()
        
        # On créé les contenus
        self.page_calendrier = MDDatePicker(callback=self.get_date,year=2020,month=11,day=4)
        self.page_chat = ChatPage()

        # On créé leur contenant
        self.tab_calendrier = Tab(text="Calendrier")
        self.tab_chat = Tab(text="Discuter")
        
        

        print("WINDOW SIZE : ", Window.size)
        print("--- MDTOOLBAR (WIDTH,HEIGHT) : (", self.root.ids.tabs.width, ")")
        print("--- MDTOOLBAR POS : ",self.root.ids.toolbar.width.pos)
        print("--- MDTABS (WIDTH,HEIGHT) : (",self.root.ids.tabs.width ,",", self.root.ids.tabs.tab_bar_height, ")")
        print("--- MDTABS POS : ", self.root.ids.tabs.pos)
        print("-----------------------------------------------")`
```

Here is my KV file

```
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import MDTabsBase kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabsBase
#:import MDBoxLayout kivymd.uix.boxlayout.MDBoxLayout
#:import MDToolbar kivymd.uix.toolbar.MDToolbar

<BiBOTApp>:
    toolbar: toolbar
    tabs: tabs
    
    MDBoxLayout:
        id : box
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint : {"top" : 1}
         

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "BiBOT v1"
        md_bg_color: 0.5843, 0, 0.2392, 1
        height: self.parent.height / 10
        width: self.parent.width
            
    MDTabs:
        id: tabs
        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)
        background_color: 0.5843, 0.7529, 0.2392, 1
        text_color_normal: 0, 0, 0, 1
        text_color_active: 0, 0, 0, 1 
        tab_bar_height : self.parent.height / 10
        width: self.parent.width
```

Here is the error I get

```
WINDOW SIZE :  (800, 600)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\h.gaudard\Desktop\kivyMD\KivyMD-master\demos\anthony\Tab.py", line 111, in <module>
     BiBOTApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\h.gaudard\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\mobile_app\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Users\h.gaudard\Desktop\kivyMD\KivyMD-master\demos\anthony\Tab.py", line 63, in build
     print("--- MDTOOLBAR (WIDTH,HEIGHT) : (", self.root.ids.tabs.width, ")")
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids'
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here:

- Your `kv` file is named `bibot.kv`, which means that it will get loaded automatically by kivy. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv). Loading that same `kv` file explicitly in your `build()` method is a bad idea as loading the same `kv` file multiple times will likely lead to errors.
- The `kv` file is used to define a `Widget` tree, not the `App` itself. So your `kv` file should either have one root widget rule (one that is not enclosed in `<>`) or rule/rules that are used in your `build()` method.

So, one fix for your problem is to modify your `kv` file to provide a legitimate root widget rule:

```
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import MDTabsBase kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabsBase
#:import MDBoxLayout kivymd.uix.boxlayout.MDBoxLayout
#:import MDToolbar kivymd.uix.toolbar.MDToolbar

# root widget rule
BoxLayout:
    toolbar: toolbar
    tabs: tabs

    MDBoxLayout:
        id : box
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint : {"top" : 1}


    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "BiBOT v1"
        md_bg_color: 0.5843, 0, 0.2392, 1
        height: self.parent.height / 10
        width: self.parent.width

    MDTabs:
        id: tabs
        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)
        background_color: 0.5843, 0.7529, 0.2392, 1
        text_color_normal: 0, 0, 0, 1
        text_color_active: 0, 0, 0, 1
        tab_bar_height : self.parent.height / 10
        width: self.parent.width
```

and remove the explicit load from the `build()` method:

```
def build(self):
    # KV = Builder.load_file("bibot.kv")
    # print(type(KV))
    # layout = BoxLayout()

    # On créé les contenus
    self.page_calendrier = MDDatePicker(callback=self.get_date,year=2020,month=11,day=4)
    self.page_chat = ChatPage()

    # On créé leur contenant
    self.tab_calendrier = Tab(text="Calendrier")
    self.tab_chat = Tab(text="Discuter")



    print("WINDOW SIZE : ", Window.size)
    print("--- MDTOOLBAR (WIDTH,HEIGHT) : (", self.root.ids.tabs.width, ")")
    print("--- MDTOOLBAR POS : ",self.root.ids.toolbar.pos)
    print("--- MDTABS (WIDTH,HEIGHT) : (",self.root.ids.tabs.width ,",", self.root.ids.tabs.tab_bar_height, ")")
    print("--- MDTABS POS : ", self.root.ids.tabs.pos)
    print("-----------------------------------------------")
```

Note that the lines in the above method that create a `MDDatePicker` and a `ChatPage` will have no effect, since the created Widgets are not added to the GUI.